# Call procedures of a declared object from a class that is in no way connected

Tags: java, class, logging, output

I've been attempting to write a server program for a game and one issue that I am experiencing is writing to my 'log' (which is just a JTextArea's caption) from another class/thread. Basically, the setup is this:

MainWindow:

-JTextArea with the log.

Threads are started from MainWindow. They may need to output something, and basically what I am after is instead of printing whatever these threads need to output to `System.out` I can print them to my log, in my MainWindow (which is a JFrame). Is there a way to access the MainWindow from the threads? I don't really know how else to explain this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is made for that purpose.

```
final String labelText = "current label text";
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Write your GUI updater code here
        // like this
        labelOnTheGui.setText(labelText);
    }
});
```

This is the only way you can manipulate the GUI starting the action from a different thread.